# Why is a syntax error shown at the "+" sign on the second line?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Why does the "+" below dlginfo.txtInfo.text always show a syntax error in Visual Basic? How can I fix it?

```
dlgInfo.Show()
dlgInfo.txtInfo.Text = " Nama : " + txtnama.Text + vbCrLf
         " Tanggal Lahir : " + timTanggalLahir.Text + vbCrLf + " Jenis Kelamin : " + jenis_kelamin + vbCrLf + " Agama : " + boAgama.Text + vbCrLf + " Pekerjaan : " + lstPekerjaan.Text + vbCrLf + " Hobi : " + hobi + vbCrLf + " Kendaraan : " + lstKendaraan.Text + vbCrLf + " Motto Hidup : " + txtMottoHidup.Text
```

Comment: There is no operator at the end of the line `dlgInfo.txtInfo.Text = " Nama : " + txtnama.Text + vbCrLf` so it can't tell that the next line has anything to do with that. Writing `dlgInfo.txtInfo.Text = " Nama : " & txtnama.Text & vbCrLf &` would fix it. (The string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`, but the latter will work.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton: unfortunately, `&` and `+` are both [valid string concatenation operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operators). MS has thrown out so many things from VB Classic in VB.NET, but this oddity is still a thing. I wish they had removed it, too. I encourage everybody to exclusively use `&` for string concatenation.

Comment: @Dai Using `&` is one of the places where [implicit line continuation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/statements#implicit-line-continuation) works.

Comment: @Dai VB.Net added support for this a few releases back (I think 2016).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn A bit earlier than that: [Implicit Line Continuation in VB 2010](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/06/implicit-line-continuation-in-vb-2010.html).

Comment: I notice that the question is tagged with "visual-studio-2010" - is that *really* the version which you are using? It will make a difference to the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Of the three lines in the question (including `dlgInfo.Show()`), the problem is between the end of the second line and the beginning of the third. Put them together and you get this:

```
vbCrLf " Tanggal Lahir : "
```

There's no operator between those two expressions. Since that would be invalid syntax, the compiler interprets the second line as a completed statement, and then begins processing the third line as a new statement.

So now let's look at just the first two terms of this new statement:

```
 " Tanggal Lahir : " + timTanggalLahir.Text
```

This is a valid **expression**, that concatenates a new string from two smaller strings. However, it's not valid as an opening to a **statement**. And so we see a syntax error at  the `+` operator, because it's the operation that is invalid. We need an assignment, function call, or variable declaration here; not addition or concatenation that goes nowhere.

To fix it, we can add another concatenation operator to the end of the second line:

```
dlgInfo.txtInfo.Text = " Nama : " + txtnama.Text + vbCrLf +
```

This will let VB.Net know to continue processing the next line as part of the same statement.

Or we can compact this to use string interpolation, so it (almost) fits on one line:

```
dlgInfo.txtInfo.Text = $" Nama : {txtnama.Text}{vbCrLf} Tanggal Lahir : {timTanggalLahir.Text}{vbCrLf} Jenis Kelamin : {jenis_kelamin}{vbCrLf} Agama : {boAgama.Text}{vbCrLf} Pekerjaan : {lstPekerjaan.Text}{vbCrLf} Hobi : {hobi}{vbCrLf} Kendaraan : {lstKendaraan.Text}{vbCrLf} Motto Hidup : {txtMottoHidup.Text}"
```

But that's still kind of long. What I would probably do is use an interpolated multi-line string literal to naturally separate the code on the line breaks, so the code more closely resembles the target string:

```
 dlgInfo.txtInfo.Text = 
 $" Nama : {txtnama.Text}
  Tanggal Lahir : {timTanggalLahir.Text}
  Jenis Kelamin : {jenis_kelamin}
  Agama : {boAgama.Text}
  Pekerjaan : {lstPekerjaan.Text}
  Hobi : {hobi}
  Kendaraan : {lstKendaraan.Text}
  Motto Hidup : {txtMottoHidup.Text}"
```

Comment: Also, I wasn't sure this would work at first (I [had to verify it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ByzIPT) before posting), so TIL interpolated strings and multiline string literals can work together.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is nothing to suggest that the third line is part of the second line shown in the question - there is no binary operator, such as `&`, at the end of the second line.

The preferred string concatenation operator in VB.NET is [`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operator), which does a bit more than the [`+`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addition-operator) operator between operands.

However, in this case, it would make the code easier to read and maintain if it used a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) to create the string, especially as that has an AppendLine method that means you don't need to keep appending VbCrLf, something like this:

```
Imports System.Text
`....
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
sb.AppendLine($" Nama : {txtnama.Text}")
sb.AppendLine($" Tanggal Lahir : {timTanggalLahir.Text}")
sb.AppendLine($" Jenis Kelamin : {jenis_kelamin}")
sb.AppendLine($" Agama : {boAgama.Text}")
sb.AppendLine($" Pekerjaan : {lstPekerjaan.Text}")
sb.AppendLine($" Hobi : {hobi}")
sb.AppendLine($" Kendaraan : {lstKendaraan.Text}")
sb.Append($" Motto Hidup : {txtMottoHidup.Text}")

dlgInfo.txtInfo.Text = sb.ToString()
```

You can see how much easier that would be to modify in the future; writing code which is easy to maintain is important. Let the compiler sort out any optimisations to the code, that is its job.

---

If you are using a version of Visual Studio before interpolated strings were introduced (VB14, which was in VS2015):

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
sb.AppendLine(" Nama : " & txtnama.Text)
sb.AppendLine(" Tanggal Lahir : " & timTanggalLahir.Text)
sb.AppendLine(" Jenis Kelamin :   " & jenis_kelamin)
sb.AppendLine(" Agama : " & boAgama.Text)
sb.AppendLine(" Pekerjaan   " & lstPekerjaan.Text)
sb.AppendLine(" Hobi : " & hobi)
sb.AppendLine(" Kendaraan   " & lstKendaraan.Text)
sb.Append(" Motto Hidup : " & txtMottoHidup.Text)
```